# Update software will also update the OS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates

I have Samsung Galaxy S-Duos with Android Version 4.0.4.
I always get Software Update Popup.
If I will confirm the update then it will update the Android Version Also or just update all the system software's only?

Comment: [Galaxy S-Duos only supports up to Android 4.0 officially](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_duos_s7562-4883.php), so I doubt it will upgrade the Android OS to 4.1 or later.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. So Should I try to update it or not?

Comment: Well... it's up to you, as the user and owner of the device. If you're still in doubt, you may try to find some info about the particular update (is there any size? date?), but generally, an update should improve something (even though it might break others...)

Answer (score 1):

It only updates the apps. How ever you can update the OS by Going to Settings > (More) > About device > Software update > update.